# how can I fill a form with information I want to edit in laravel 5.5?

Tags: laravel, web, edit, crud

I'm new in laravel and I want to make a form to edit data from my database so the user just have to change some fields, I would be glad if somebody could give me an example.

I'm using laravel 5.5 and mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check out this edit example in laravel -

In Routes

```
Route::get('PartnerType/edit/{id}', 'PartnerTypeController@edit');
Route::post('PartnerType/update', 'PartnerTypeController@update');
```

In controller,

```
   public function edit($id){
       $data['propertyType'] = PropertyType::where('id', $id)->first();
       return view('propertyType.edit', $data);
   }

   public function update(Request $request){
        //Validate user inputs
        $validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), ['name' => 'required']);

        //Check whether validation is failed or passed
        if($validator->fails()){
            //Redirect back with validation errors
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator->errors())->withInput();
        }

        //Save Details
        $propertyType = PartnerType::where('id', $request->id)->first();
        $propertyType->name = $request->name;
        $propertyType->save();

        //Redirect with success message
        return redirect()->to('manage/PartnerType/show')->with('success', 'PartnerType updated successfully');
    }
```

In view ,

```
    {!! Form::model($propertyType, array('url'=>array('manage/propertyType/update'), 'method' => 'POST', 'id' => 'edit_propertyType_form')) !!}      
        <div class="form-body pb0">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$propertyType->id}}">
                {!! Form::label('name', 'Name*') !!}
                <div class="input-group">                               
                   {!! Form::text('name', $propertyType->name, array('class' => 'form-control','id' => 'name', 'placeholder' => 'Name')) !!} 
                </div>
           </div>
        <div class="status-label">
          {!! Form::submit('Submit',array('class' => 'btn blue')) !!}
       </div>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is kind of vague as what you intend to do. Have you tried something out? if so, what is it?

Let's start from the beginning:

As far as I can tell right now (need more details) you need:

1. A view file (example: edit.blade.php) which will be inside the folder resources/views and inside the folder you have to create with the proper name (example: /resources/views/something/edit.blade.php)
2. Then create the form where the user is going to edit the information from the database.
3. Go to your routes folder and web.php file to set the routes you will need in order to PUT/PATCH the new information from the form to de DB.
4. Do you have your database configured already?

Please send more information, and I will answer more in detail on what you need or you can go to the [official documentation](http://laravel.com) for further information as well.